# How to save a UITableView's content as a PNG file?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, png

My application with a UITableView inside the contentview, and the tableview's contentsize is out of the contentview, when I use following code to generate PNG file from the tableview, only the visible content generated. But I wanna the whole tableview to be generated as the final PNG file, How can do?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self._tableView.contentSize);
[self._tableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

return UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it does not seem possible because the content of the table view will only available when its `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` will be called for that indexpath. And it will be only called when tableview cell is visible. And as the content is unavailable you can not save it as PNG.